# Can an asynchronous task be run in a loop? (in iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, loops, firebase

basically I'm using firebase to query a user's 'status' property and doing so in a do/while loop.

If the status property is free then i want to break the loop and continue with the rest of the method. If the status property is not free then I want to query firebase again for a new user until a free user is found.

My firebase code works fine outside the loop but doesn't seem to be called inside of it. Here is the loop:

```
__block uint32_t rando; 
self.freedom = @"about to check";

do {
//check if free

[self checkIfFree:^(BOOL finished) {

    if (finished) {
        if ([self.freedom isEqualToString:@"free"]) {
            //should break loop here
        }

        else if ([self.freedom isEqualToString:@"matched"]){

            //get another user

            do {
                //picking another random user from array
                rando = arc4random_uniform(arraycount);
            }
            while (rando == randomIndex && rando == [self.randString intValue]);

            self.randString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", rando];
            [users removeAllObjects];
            [users addObject:[usersArray objectAtIndex:rando]];
            self.freeUser = [users objectAtIndex:0];

            //should repeat check here but doesn't work
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"error!");
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"not finished the checking yet");
    }
}];
} while (![self.freedom  isEqual: @"free"]);
```

And here's my firebase code:

```
-(void)checkIfFree:(myCompletion) compblock{

self.freeUserFB = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://skipchat.firebaseio.com/users/%@", self.freeUser.objectId]];

[self.freeUserFB observeEventType:FEventTypeValue  withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
 {
     self.otherStatus = snapshot.value[@"status"];

     NSLog(@"snapshot info %@", snapshot.value);

     if ([self.otherStatus isEqualToString:@"free"]) {
         self.userIsFree = YES;
         self.freedom = @"free";
     }
     else{
         self.userIsFree = NO;
         self.freedom = @"matched";             
     }
     compblock(YES);
 }];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: you should use an enum or at least named string constants instead of stuff like `self.freedom = @"free";` `self.freedom = @"matched";`

Comment: Why don't you just add an observer to see when the status changes: FEventTypeChildChanged. Then you can check the users status and add them to an array of free users if they are free?

Comment: I don't think this would do the job because I want a value at that point in time so the current user can be matched to another free user instantly. The type of user queried for is also up for changing based on the user's current preferences (like tinder) so this would require looking at all the users i guess? 

Also I would still run into the issue of if the free users array is empty i would have to call the async firebase method again I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand correctly your question.
If you want to run your completion code again till some condition is matched (in this case `[self.freedom isEqualToString:@"free"]`) you can do the following (removing the do - while):

```
void( ^ myResponseBlock)(BOOL finished) = ^ void(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        if ([self.freedom isEqualToString: @"free"]) {
            return;
        } else if ([self.freedom isEqualToString: @"matched"]) {
            //get another user
            do {
                //picking another random user from array
                rando = arc4random_uniform(arraycount);
            }
            while (rando == randomIndex && rando == [self.randString intValue]);
            self.randString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u", rando];
            [users removeAllObjects];
            [users addObject:usersArray[rando]];
            self.freeUser = users.firstObject;

            // Schedule another async check
            [self checkIfFree: myResponseBlock];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error!");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not finished the checking yet");
    }
};

[self checkIfFree: myResponseBlock];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this asap. 

Just wondering why this should work and why a do/while loop would not?

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting an error 'bad access' on the last line of my 'checkIfFree' completion block: 'completion(YES)'

Comment: Got it working, thanks for the help! see for solving the 'bad access' error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388668/bad-access-after-block-within-a-block-is-called-ios